# Что такое блок в БЭМ?

Tags: css, бэм

Я смотрю разные видо про БЭМ и не понимаю, что там говорится о том, что такое блок. Они говорят, что блоком может быть что угодно – кнопка, иконка и тд. Что это элемент, который можно переиспользовать. Я так понимаю, что тут имеется ввиду, что если у элементов одинаковые свойства, то можно просто не создавать несколько классов, а просто использовать один класс для нескольких элементов. То есть блок - это класс, который используется много раз для разных элементов. Потом в видео говорится, что блоки можно вкладывать друг в друга бесконечное количество раз. Я не понимаю, о чём тут говорится. Что значит вкладывать друг в друга бесконечное количество раз? Что такое блок? Это класс, который используется для нескольких элементов или что? Как будто сначала они говорят о блоке, как о классе, который используется с несколькими элементами, а потом они говорят о блоке, как об контейнере, который содержит какие-то элементы. Как будто сперва они имеют ввиду под термином ‟блок” одно, а потом совершенно другое.

Comment: Стоит начать с [документации и основных понятий](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/)